# How to efficiently program a specific unitary transformation operating on a vector avoiding np.dot

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, handle

I'm setting a library of quantum gates (unitary operators).
I want to write them as abstractly as possible, so that I can use them for many purposes.

For example, the Hadamard gate.

Imagine we have a string of n bits: |abc...n>.
These strings represent numbers from 0 to 2^n, and they make for a computational basis, of elements |00...0>, |00...1>, ..., |11...1>.
Let's say our state is a linear combination of some bit strings, and we express it as a vector of 2^n components:

```
state = [a00...0, ..., a11...1]
```

The Hadamard Gate takes as arguments the current state and an integer m<=n.
We say the Hadamard Gate is acting on the m'th qubit.

On a practical example, supose we are working with 3 qubits.
Our computational basis is:

```
|000>, |001>, |010>, |011>,
|100>, |101>, |110>, |111>
```

And our states will be complex 8-dimensional arrays.

```
state = [a000, a001, a010, a011, a100, a101, a110, a111]
```

What the Hadamard Gate on the 1st qubit does is:

```
H(state) = [b000, b001, b010, b011, b100, b101, b110, b111]
```

with

```
b0XY = 1/sqrt(2) * (a0XY + a1XY)
b1XY = 1/sqrt(2) * (a0XY - a1XY)
```

for any X and Y.

And, for instance, the same would happen if we applied a Hadamard Gate on the third qubit of a 4-qubit system:

```
state = [a0000, a0001, ..., a1111]
H(state) = [b0000, b0001, ..., b1111]
```

with

```
bXX0X = 1/sqrt(2) (aXX0X + aXX1X)
bXX1X = 1/sqrt(2) (aXX0X - aXX1X)
```

This is my code, where ``size" is the dimension, the amount of qubits.
The initial state is a00...0 = 1 and 0 elsewhere, but that is not too important, it could be anything.

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import math

state = np.zeros(2**size, dtype=complex)
state[0] = 1.

def ii (self,i):
    """Computes a double index.

    Args.
        i (vector): array of bits with value 1 or 0.

    Rets.
        ii (int): base 10 representation of the bits array.
    """
    l = len(i)
    return np.dot(i,[2**(l-j-1) for j in range(l)])

def H(state, m):
    """Apply the Hadamard Gate to the m'th qubit.

    Args.
        state (dim=2**size vector): initial state.
        m (int): what qubit are we applying our gate on.

    Rets.
        state (dim=2**n vector): new final state.
    """
    for i in product([0,1], repeat=self.size):
        # can improve, just looking for a working model
        j = np.array(i)
        j[m] ^= 1
        if(j[m]):
            state[ii(i)] += state[ii(j)]
        else:
            state[ii(i)] = state[ii(j)] - 2*state[ii(i)]

    state /= math.sqrt(2)
    return state
```

What can I do to improve the efficiency?

The output is alright right now.
I would like to deal in a more elegant way with the three lines under the comment.
I would also like to know how to deal with the vector transformation using handles, so no memory or time is wasted. (I come from a humble C background, and still don't know what the equivalent to handles in Python is).

Thanks and have a good one!

Comment: Can you post the mathematical operation you are actually doing there? Maybe some sweet TeX? It has been some time since I worked with Hadamard operators

Comment: You are thinking too much like a C programmer here.  Python in interpreted, not compiled; too much is going on under the surface to worry about memory allocations.  We might help if you set up a clear working example, a function with inputs, defined outside of a class (all those `self.` links are distracting).  What's `self.size`?  At first glance that `np.array(i)` step might be the most expensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, I very much appreciate it. I added a less cumbersome explanation, but I'm afraid I don't know how to write TeX here, I'm not very used to posting questions. Also, I understand my mindset might be too C-oriented, I would just like to know what is the most efficient way of performing this simple operation. Thanks to both of you!